# images disappear on edit&save item in magento admin custom module

Tags: image, magento

I have created magento custom module for admin.There is image field and its storing images fine but when I edit this item and save ,image is disappear because query is updating all the columns in database.Can someone please tell me How can I update  only selected columns? or any other solution for this problem.Please help me

Thanks,
Irphan